# How to implement calculation in access 2003

Tags: c#, ms-access-2003

I have an `access database` that am trying to add some calculation and use my `c#` application to pull data using a `dataGridView`,

I have about 14 fields in this particular table, I was wondering if there is way

I could perform a calculation from `field 1` based on field `11` and `12?`
both field `11` and `12` are accepts numbers and so too field 1 I want field one to have data that is as  `field1==>{field11-field12)`
How can I accomplish this in access 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a query in Access, then you can enter the calculation as a new field in that query. When you create the query, Access will give you a series of checkboxes where you can select which fields you want in the result.

It is easiest to add the calculation if you go to SQL view in the query editor. Then you will see something like

```
select field2, field3, field4 from SomeTable
```

and you want to add your calculation as a new column

```
select field2, field3, field4, (field11 - field12) as fieldDifference from SomeTable
```

Then save your query.

In your C# code, instead of having the data source refer to the table name (`SomeTable` in this example) use the name that you saved the query as.